# Cutting lines in shapefile following GPX-source

Tags: qgis, shapefile, gpx

I have a OSM-Shapefile containing all roads of a given area. I need an overlay cut out of this source-Shapefile that contains only some routes that I want to highlight on my map. I have some GPX-Tracks that show those routes, but they aren't precise enough to use them directly as an overlay.

How can I use those GPX-Tracks to select the corresponding roads of the original shapefile, cut them out and copy them in a new shapefile?

Is it possible to set a certain "buffer area" for selecting lines also if they don't exactly overlay with the GPX-file?

I'm using QGIS.